# Add Custom Error messages in Sails Auth

Tags: sails.js

```
{
  "Error.Passport.Password.Invalid": "The provided password is invalid!",
  "Error.Passport.Password.Wrong": "Whoa, that password wasn't quite right!",
  "Error.Passport.Password.NotSet": "Oh no, you haven't set a password yet!",
  "Error.Passport.Username.NotFound": "Uhm, what's your name again?",
  "Error.Passport.User.Exists": "This username is already taken.",
  "Error.Passport.Email.NotFound": "That email doesn't seem right",
  "Error.Passport.Email.Missing": "You need to supply an email-address for verification",
  "Error.Passport.Email.Exists": "This email already exists. So try logging in.",
  "Error.Passport.Username.Missing": "You need to supply a username",
  "Error.Passport.Password.Missing": "Oh no, you haven't set a password yet!",
  "Error.Passport.Generic": "Snap. Something went wrong with authorization."
}
```

where do i need to add this error messages to show custom error messages in Sails Auth?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this on your localisation files under config/locales/{{lang}}.json
And restart server for reload locales files

Comment: hi thank you for your quick response i added those in to the en.json in the config/locales/ but it is still not reflecting.

Comment: If you have only english version remove others locales file and change under config/i18n.js change "locales" properties

Comment: Thank you for your response, i updated the i18n.js file and i did sails lift again but still it is not reflecting in the api response